# Integration Problem: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_0\sqrt{w}e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}dw$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I know that:$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_0\sqrt{w}e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}dw=\frac{1}{{(x^2+2)}^{3/2}}$$
I've attempted to solve this with integration by parts $\int{fdg}=fg-\int{dfg}$

I let

$$\begin{array} ff=\sqrt{w} & dg=e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}\\df=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}& g=\frac{-2e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}}{2+x^2}{}\end{array}$$

Which is:$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\bigr[\frac{-2\sqrt{w}e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}}{2+x^2}\Bigr|^{\infty}_{0}+\frac{1}{2+x^2}\int^{\infty}_0\frac{e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{w}}dw\bigr]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\bigr[\frac{1}{2+x^2}\int^{\infty}_0\frac{e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{w}}dw\bigr]$$

I have to integrate by parts again, this time I have:

$$\begin{array} ff=e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}} & dg=\frac{1}{\sqrt{w}}\\df=\frac{(x^2+2)^2e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}}{2}& g=2\sqrt{w}\end{array}$$
Which is:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigr[\frac{1}{x^2+2}\bigr(2\sqrt{w}e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}\Bigr|^{\infty}_{0}+(x^2+2)\int^{\infty}_{0}\sqrt{w}e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}dw\bigr)\bigr]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_0\sqrt{w}e^{-w-\frac{wx^2}{2}}dw$$

So, I'm back to where I started. Can somebody spot my mistake?

Comment: I guess you went one step to the north and then one step to the south...It happens sometimes with integration by part to end after applying it twice to end where you have started..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint***

you have nearly with $w=u^2 \implies dw=2udu$ this:

$$I=\int \sqrt w e^{-w}dw=2\int u^2e^{-u^2}du$$
$$I=2\int u\times ue^{-u^2}du=\int u\times (-e^{-u^2})'du$$
Integrate by part once...
$$\int_0^{\infty} u\times (-e^{-u^2})'du=(u\times (-e^{-u^2}))|_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty} (-e^{-u^2})du$$
And use gaussian integral to get the value of the last integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-u^2}du=\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}2$$